# Unable to perform complex nesting in mongodb queries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

how to perform complete nesting in mongodbquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this, here is an example by nesting `$lookup`'s :

```
[
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'questionsanwereds',
            'let': {id: '$_id'},
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$$id", "$reqId"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$questions"
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "questions",
                        localField: "questions.questionId",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "questionObj"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$unwind": "$questionObj"
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$_id",
                        questions: {
                            $push: {
                                comment: "$comment",
                                name: "$questionObj.name",
                                optionSelected: "$optionSelected"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            'as': 'questionsAnswereds'
        }
    },
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$questionsAnswereds'
        }
    }
]
```

The strategy is populating the name of each question separately and then grouping to restore the required structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help but getting {"message":"FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."}

Comment: It's a minor syntax error in the nested lookup. remove the `$` from the `localField`

Comment: Still getting a empty a value in the nested obect
```
{
                    $unwind: "$questions"
                }

```
i think its because of this

Comment: I used your code there and relied on your schema. make sure the first `lookup` is successful first (only using the $match in the pipeline). according to what you posted it should be.

Comment: in the first lookup till the $group its working fine but on applying group the result set is becoming empty.And should I place my query and then attach to it.Or else jst put only ur code in the aggregte

Comment: `$group` can't "delete" objects so it doesn't add up. any chance you add real data sample to https://mongoplayground.net/ so i can take a look?

Comment: rtoreqs schema data:-https://mongoplayground.net/p/jtmdUk2jb4N
questionsanwereds schema:-https://mongoplayground.net/p/vVxcHhAGuSH
questions:-https://mongoplayground.net/p/lGtzvpAApHY

Comment: Where's `reqId`? you used it in your `$lookup`. also you can do multiple collections in 1 link to test `$lookup`: https://mongoplayground.net/p/s6R9_Y9GZA5

Comment: reqId is present in the questionsanwereds schema

Comment: Could you go into the link i shared and view the collection? it does not contain it and that's why the `$lookup` "fails".

Comment: Now I modified the schema and here is the url:-https://mongoplayground.net/p/wu4VWfco8Qr  and unable to change questionId to questionName

Comment: Ok great, now one final mistake i found was the inner `$lookup`'s `localField` should be changed into: `localField: "questions.questionId"` and now everything should work as expected.

Comment: Question Name im getting but option selected is disappered .https://mongoplayground.net/p/tPQNKFiVN1G

Comment: It's not part of the `$project`, you should just add whichever fields you want to that stage. this was just a quick example on how to solve your issues.